# QML property binding for repeater item

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

How do property bindings work for repeater items? I am trying to use a property binding on an element generated by a repeater, but the binding doesn't work:

```
Rectangle
{
   id: root
   property int currentLocation: 0

   Button {
        text: "Change location"
        onClicked: root.currentLocation = (root.currentLocation + 1) % 2
    }

    Repeater {
            id: locationlRepeater
            model: locationModel
            Item {
                visible: root.currentLocation == model.location   // Why doesn't this update on button click?
                Text {
                   id: locationText
                   text: "Location: " + model.location
                }
            }
    }
 
    ListModel {
        id: locationModel
        ListElement {
            location: 0
            // etc.
        }
        ListElement {
            location: 1
            // etc.
        }
}
```

Updated: using Qt 5.6.2

Comment: Your code works for me. I see text `Location: 0` at first, and then after the button press, it switches to `Location: 1`.

Comment: Same here. Are you sure this is a minimal _reproducible_ example? Maybe update the question with your Qt version etc. To answer your question: they work the same, you have to take care that the scope breaks a bit, but you did in this example by referencing `root.currentLocation`

Comment: Your code is completely working for me

Comment: Qt version 5.6.2. It seems the expression for 'visible' is evaluated at component creation time, and the binding is never updated.

Comment: Indeed I had problems 'further up', which for some reason didn't manifest immediately. I think because I was only 'running' and not 'building' in Qt Creator. Thank you.